# tick format produces overlapping labels

Tags: d3.js

I am currently using:

```
var formatValue = d3.format("s");
```

and then

```
var axisX = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale( someXscale )
    .tickFormat (function( d ) { return formatValue(d); } );
```

This code produces the following when I zoom (from the highest zoom to the lowest):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The values on this axis can go up to 3,100,000,000.

I don't like the fact that the values fall on top of each other and less important I would like the labels to have Giga, Mega, Kilo.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A good way can be drawn from [this comment](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2241#issuecomment-150099953) by M. Bostock:

```
var formatAbbreviation = d3.format(".2s");

formatAbbreviation(5000000000); // 5.00G
formatAbbreviation(5000000); // 5.00M
formatAbbreviation(5000); // 5.00k
```

In the post you see him actually customising the behaviour, changing `G` to `B`.

I actually created my own custom implementation in the past, maybe it can be useful.
Here's an example I've made:

```
var format = function(num) {
  var numToStr = num + '';
  var ext = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G']; // Add extensions as needed
  var size = 3; 
  var val = 0;
  var max = 5; // how many digit maximum we want on screen

  var compress = function(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    if (len <= size) {
      return str + ext[val];
    }
    if (val + 1 === ext.length) {
      return str.slice(0, max) + ext[val]; // <= what to do when the max number of digits is reached, change as needed
    }      
    val++;
    return compress(str.slice(0, str.length - size));
  }
  return compress(numToStr);
}

console.log(format(1)) // => 1
console.log(format(12)) // => 12
console.log(format(123)) // => 123
console.log(format(1234)) // => 1K
console.log(format(12345)) // => 12K
console.log(format(123456)) // => 123K
console.log(format(1234567)) // => 1M
console.log(format(12345678)) // => 12M
console.log(format(123456789)) // => 123M
console.log(format(1234567890)) // => 1G
console.log(format(12345678901)) // => 12G
console.log(format(12345678902321312)) // => 12345G

// used more or less like so in d3
var axisX = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale( someXscale )
    .tickFormat (function( d ) { return format(d); } );
```

As you notice we can define the maximum number of digits you want on screen - in this case 5 - and handle that case as we think it's best for the particular situation (every case is different).

Comment: Your suggestion `format = function(num) {}` after just 2 zoom in actions, just labels all ticks with `1K`. The `format = d3.format(".2s");` practically does the same but after 5-6 zoom in actions. I need the accuracy of my format, just less ticks on the axis as it becomes overcrowded.